# AWS Beanstalk connecting to remote mysql database

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, remote-server

I got an Laravel project up and running on AWS Beanstalk, with no RDS.  I'm looking to use a remote database that already has all the data I need.  My laravel .env file all looks good and should point to the remote database.

However, every time I try to login the credentials are pointing to :
'myusername'@'ec2-54-###-###-##.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' 
when it should be pointed to 
'myusername'@107.###.##.##

Where is the aws config file to overwrite this aws host?

Comment: You need to pass the host IP address as a Beanstalk environment variable which your Laravel application can then consume. I'm curious to know if you've already done this.

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding all of my key-pairs from Lavarel's .env file on the creation of the beanstalk application, still didn't help.  Unless if there are some default AWS key's I need to overwrite, but I don't know what those are